# datagridview cell mouse hover backcolor change

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datagridview, mouseover

i want to change the backcolor of cell in datagridview while mouse hover on particular cell.

Tried code:

```
private void dataGridView_whateventwillcomehere(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this on `CellMouseMove` Event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

You need `CellMouseLeave` Event to restore color

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: You need to mention `column name` instead of `e.ColumnIndex` for purticular cell.

Comment: also in the DGV constructor you need to set double-buffering painting, else changing the cell style provokes flickering on mouse move over the DGV `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);`